# Storing formatted QML source code in a JSON file

Tags: json, qt, qml

I need to store QML source code in a JSON file, in such a way that the formatting (newlines and spacing and whatnot) are preserved. I thought about programmatically inserting special unicode characters that I would never use in my source code as markers into the JSON (when saving it) to represent new lines and spaces. When reading the source code from JSON, I would replace these markers with either a newline or a space. However, this doesn't feel like a very robust solution.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`QByteArray::toBase64()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toBase64) to convert the QML source to a string that can be saved to JSON:

```
void SourceCodeSerialiser::read(const QJsonObject &json)
{
    mQml = QByteArray::fromBase64(json["qml"].toString().toUtf8());
}
```

And [`QByteArray::toBase64()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromBase64) to read the saved Base64 string back to a string of QML:

```
void SourceCodeSerialiser::write(QJsonObject &json) const
{
    json["qml"] = QString(mQml.toUtf8().toBase64());
}
```

(`mQml` is a `QString`)

This turns the following QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: item
}
```

into this Base64 string:

```
aW1wb3J0IFF0UXVpY2sgMi4wCgpJdGVtIHsKICAgIGlkOiBpdGVtCn0=
```

---

As mentioned by @dtech, it's also possible to compress the byte array using [`qCompress()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#qCompress) and [`qUncompress()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#qUncompress) to save some memory:

```
void SourceCodeSerialiser::read(const QJsonObject &json)
{
    mQml = qUncompress(QByteArray::fromBase64(json["qml"].toString().toUtf8()));
}

void SourceCodeSerialiser::write(QJsonObject &json) const
{
    json["qml"] = QString(qCompress(mQml.toUtf8(), 9).toBase64());
}
```

This results in the following Base64 string:

```
AAAAKXjay8wtyC8qUQgsCSzNTM5WMNIz4OLyLEnNVajmUgCCzBQrhUwgl6sWABKDDFM=
```

This is larger than the uncompressed version because the QML snippet was so small. Larger QML files will see a benefit from compression.

Comment: While you are at it, you might also compress the byte array to save on memory.

Comment: Oh, I didn't even know there was a function for that. Thanks!

Comment: @dtech `QString(qCompress(mQml.toUtf8().toBase64(), 9))` seems to result in an empty string - how would I convert the `QByteArray` to a `QString`, which `QJsonObject` requires?

Comment: Compress and then convert to base64. Also, for short sources, compression will not really do any good. It will be quite beneficial for larger ones thou.